# Adding <p> tags automatically BUT ignoring headers <h*>

Tags: php, replace

I'm using the following code:

```
$paragraph = '<p>' . str_replace("\n\n", "</p>\n<p>", $text) . '</p>';
$paragraph = str_replace("<p><h1>", "<h1>", $paragraph); 
$paragraph = str_replace("</h1></p>", "</h1>", $paragraph); 
$paragraph = str_replace("<p><h2>", "<h2>", $paragraph); 
$paragraph = str_replace("</h2></p>", "</h2>", $paragraph);
```

But it doesn't looks elegant at all!

Is there a better way?

Comment: Please provide example for how `$text` string is created. If it is HTML string, the it's better to parse it and extract specific tag contents to work with.

Answer (score 0):

just use arrays as parameters for str_replace

```
$paragraph=str_replace(array("\n\n","<p><hl>","</h1></p>","<p><h2>","</h2></p>"), array("</p>\n<p>","<h1>","</h1>","<h2>","</h2>"), $text) ;
```

You can see an example here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

check Example #1

anyways if i understand what you are trying... "each 2 line feedchange it for a

except if the next file is  or "

**then I would change it to**

```
$paragraph="<p>".str_replace("\n\n", "</p>\n<p>", $text)."</p>" ;

$paragraph=str_replace(array("<p><hl>","</h1></p>","<p><h2>","</h2></p>"), array("<h1>","</h1>","<h2>","</h2>"), $paragraph) ;
```

First line removes double line feeds for

and the  2nd will just remove all the

where headers h1 or h2 are